Crop and increase speed of videos using FFMPEG
I usually edit school videos using FFMPEG, using this command to crop the video
ffmpeg -i  "02-BC101.mp4" -vf "crop=1690:900:0:100"  -s hd480 -strict -2  "02-BC101xy.mp4" 
then use this command to increase the speed
ffmpeg -i 02-BC101xy.mp4  -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=0.625*PTS[v];[0:a]atempo=1.6[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]"  02-BC101xyD.mp4 
They consume too much time to finish in long lectures. Can I merge them into 1 command, and is there any way to reduce the time taken in this task?

try → ffmpeg -i "02-BC101.mp4" -vf "crop=1690:900:0:100,setpts=0.625*PTS" -af "atempo=1.6" -s hd480 "out.mp4"
